# JQuery script to change css element to all assigned element printed in foreach loop

Tags: php, jquery

In foreach loop, I have a script that assigns id after the counter is higher than 5. I am using jquery which on click removes id. It works, but it doesn't remove all elements assigned.

CSS code I used to hide elements.

```
<style>
  #hide{
  display:none;
</style>
```

// PHP code I use and HTML.

```
<?php 

  $i = 0:
  foreach($payemnts as $p){
    $i++;
?>
  <!-- In the div id is assigned -->
  <div class="row" <?php if($i > 5) echo 'id="hide"'?>>
    <div class="col">
      <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($id); ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($id); ?>"?>">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col">

    </div>
    <div class="col">

    </div> 
  </div>  
<?php }  /* end foreach */?>
<div class="row">
   <button type="button" onclick="showAll()" class="btn btn-sm  ">READ MORE</button> 
</div>
```

// JQUERY function I used to change CSS element of an id

```
<script>
    function showAll() { 
        $("#hide").css({'display':'flex'});  
    }
</script>
```

The solution above, after clicking on the button shows only one. It changes CSS to only one element, not to all. I need to show all elements after clicking on Read More button.

I was trying also .remove() but it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your foreach may have a typo `$payemnts`

Comment: You should use the class rather than the id. There should only be 1 element on a page with the same id. Instead of `id="hide"` change it to `class="hide"`. And then target the class with jQuery using: `$(".hide").css('display','flex');`

Comment: @JeffVdovjak thanks a lot. It works, didn't know of that rule for one 1 element.

Comment: The id attribute is meant to uniquely identify something. You can read a bit about it here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_id.asp Good luck with your project and happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

change id='hide'to class='hide'

and then

```
<script>
function showAll() { 
    $(".hide").css({'display':'flex'});  
}
```